# I'm getting a NullExceptionPointer error while trying to watch a downloaded content but streaming the same content is working fine

Tags: java, android, object, nullpointerexception

I am getting a NullPointerException Error while trying to play a Downloaded Content. I'm using a PlayerActivity class to play any content in my app. The content is being fetched using a reference number thus a getReference() method. The get reference is being fetched from a Content.class that points to the reference of any content in my API. So basically it fetches the content and plays the video in the Player Activity which is below, but the downloaded content isn't playing and when you try to play it crashes the app, then throws the Null Pointer error.

```
private Content content;
private Playback playbackObj;
private User user;

private PlaybackViewModel plvm;
private DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder BANDWIDTH_METER;
private SimpleExoPlayer player;
private StyledPlayerView playerView;



int CURRENT_WINDOW;
boolean IS_STREAM = true;
long PLAYBACK_POSITION = 0;

AlertDialog alertDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras != null){
        content = (Content) extras.getSerializable(Content.LOCAL_CONTENT_OBJECT);
        IS_STREAM = extras.getBoolean(Content.LOCAL_IS_STREAM);
    }

    plvm = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PlaybackViewModel.class);

    playbackObj = plvm.getByRef(content.getReference());
    playbackObj = playbackObj != null ? playbackObj : new Playback();


    PLAYBACK_POSITION = playbackObj.getTimeElapsed() * 1000;

    BANDWIDTH_METER = new DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(PlayerActivity.this);

    apiService = new APIService(this);
    downloadUtils = new DownloadUtils(this);

    user = new User(this);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(content.getTitle());
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }


    playerView = findViewById(R.id.playerView);
    playerView.setControllerVisibilityListener(new StyledPlayerControlView.VisibilityListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
                if(visibility == 0){
                    getSupportActionBar().show();
                }
                else{
                    getSupportActionBar().hide();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Fullscreen view
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Prevent screen from going off during playback
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


    // Prevent screenshots
    SecurityUtils.preventScreenshot(this);

    alertDialog = Utils.getSimpleDialog(this, "");

    hideSystemUi();

    mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);
    mCastSession = mCastContext.getSessionManager().getCurrentCastSession();

    initPlayer();
}
```

My error points here `playbackObj = plvm.getByRef(content.getReference());`

Here is the error thrown

```
**E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.mychoicetv.app, PID: 28228
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.mychoicetv.app/org.mychoicetv.app.playback.PlayerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.mychoicetv.app.library.models.Content.getReference()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3303)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.mychoicetv.app.library.models.Content.getReference()' on a null object reference
        at org.mychoicetv.app.playback.PlayerActivity.onCreate(PlayerActivity.java:145)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)**
```

Comment: Move the lines of code within `if(extras != null)` conditional

Comment: @Zain i've tried to move the code but to no avail.. or what did you mean by moving the code?

Comment: The problem that `content` is null, so you need to wrap the code the uses it in null safety check